# Analytical solutions to scalar field equation with Higgs-like potential

Tags: special-relativity, wavefunction, field-theory, higgs, classical-field-theory

I'm considering the ***classical** field theory* of a real scalar field $\phi$ with the Higgs "Mexican hat" potential:
$$\tag{1}
\mathcal{V}(\phi) = \frac{\lambda}{4} (\phi^2 - \phi_0^2)^2,
$$
where $\lambda > 0$ and $\phi_0$ are constants.  $\phi_0$ is the value of the "true vacuum" field.  The equation of motion of the self-interacting field is this (I'm using the metric signature $\eta = (1, -1, -1, -1)$ and units such that $c \equiv 1$):
$$\tag{2}
\eta^{ab} \, \partial_a \, \partial_b \, \phi + \lambda (\phi^2 - \phi_0^2) \, \phi = 0.
$$
I already know the "kink" solution to this equation (and its Lorentz boosted variation):
$$\tag{3}
\phi(x) = \phi_0 \tanh \Bigl( \sqrt{\frac{\lambda}{2}} \, \phi_0 \, x \Bigr).$$
It's usefull to scale the variables to simplify things a bit:
\begin{align}
\Phi &= \frac{\phi}{\phi_0}, \tag{4} \\[1ex]
T&= \sqrt{\frac{\lambda}{2}} \, \phi_0 \, t, \tag{5} \\[1ex]
X &= \sqrt{\frac{\lambda}{2}} \, \phi_0 \, x, &Y &= \sqrt{\frac{\lambda}{2}} \, \phi_0 \, y, &Z &= \sqrt{\frac{\lambda}{2}} \, \phi_0 \, z. \tag{6}
\end{align}
This way, equation (2) becomes
$$\tag{7}
\frac{\partial^2 \Phi}{\partial T^2} -  \frac{\partial^2 \Phi}{\partial X^2}-  \frac{\partial^2 \Phi}{\partial Y^2}- \frac{\partial^2 \Phi}{\partial Z^2} + 2(\Phi^2 - 1) \, \Phi = 0.
$$
So my question is this:  What are the other known **analytical solutions** to this equation, apart the "kink" solution (3) ? (i.e. $\Phi(X) = \tanh X$ and its trivial Lorentz boosted version).  Are there other non-trivial solutions known of this equation?

---

**EDIT1:**. The first part of this paper (may 2020 !) is interesting and appears to answer my question: https://arxiv.org/abs/1911.02064.  Apparently, there is no other known analytical solution! :-(

**EDIT2:**  The author of the previous paper is wrong (about non-existence of other analytical solutions).  I've found a nice solution, that I exposed in an answer below.  It comes from this book (see section 13.2.4, page 376):

**Cosmic Strings and Other Topological Defects**. Vilenkin and Shellard.

https://books.google.ca/books?id=eW4bB_LAthEC

Comment: Is the kink solution dependent on only one space-time variable?

Comment: @ggcg, yes, this solution only depends on one spatial coordinate ($x$ here), but it may be made dependent on $x - v t$ from a Lorentz boost (change of referential).  I'm looking for other nontrivial solutions.

Comment: The general solution is $\phi \left( T,X,Y,Z \right) =\tanh \left( {C_1}+{C_2}\,T+{
C_3}\,X+{C_4}\,Y-\sqrt {{{C_2}}^{2}-{{C_3}}^{2}-{{
C_4}}^{2}+1}\,Z \right)$

Comment: @Eli, that's not the general solution.  It's just the kink solution with some rotation of the axes, and a Lorentz boost, plus a simple translation.

Comment: this is more then your solution?

Answer (score 3):

There's definitely other non-trivial solutions, although there is no situation I can think of where they would be useful. But anyway, you can for example try solutions of the form
$$
\Phi(x,y,z,t)=g(x+\alpha t)
$$
for some constant $\alpha$. Plugging this ansatz into your equation we get
$$
(\alpha ^2-1) g''(x)+2g(x)^3-2 g(x)=0
$$
with solution
$$
g(x)=\epsilon\,  \mathrm{sn}\left(\frac{x-x_0}{\sqrt{\frac{\alpha ^2-1}{\epsilon ^2-2}}}\left|\frac{\epsilon ^2}{2-\epsilon ^2}\right.\right)
$$
where $\epsilon,x_0$ are integration constants, and $\mathrm{sn}$ denotes the Jacobi elliptic function. In a certain limit this function becomes the hyperbolic tangent, unsurprisingly.

You can try other ansätze and get other analytical solutions, if you are lucky. Again, this feels like a somewhat pointless exercise but that's none of my busyness :-)

Comment: Is this solution gives some simple expressions, in some limits (excluding the hyperbolic $\tanh$)?  I don't think this is a pointless exercice, since the solution could be used as a base for some numerical resolution with perturbations.  And the solutions could teach us something about the field behavior.  Do you think the kink solution is pointless?

Comment: @Cham Yes, I was commenting on my lack of imagination rather than the legitimacy of your query. I was trying to say "here's the solution, I don't know what to do with it". I'm sure people smarter than me will find plenty of applications to this type of solutions :-)

Comment: I just found a paper which describes your solution in more details: https://arxiv.org/abs/0907.4053.  I'm now very sceptic that we could find some *simple* analytical solutions similar to the famous kink solution.

Comment: Look out the interesting solution that I gave as an answer!

Comment: @Cham huh, that is definitely a neat find! It has a cute physical interpretation, I would have never guessed that solution.

Answer (score 1):

I just found an interesting analytical and highly non-trivial solution to equations (2) and (7) !
$$\tag{1}
\Phi(T, X, Y, Z) = \tanh \bigl(Z + \mathcal{G}(a T - b X - c Y) \bigr),
$$
where $a$, $b$ and $c$ are arbitrary constants satisfying the light like condition on the orthogonal plane of $Z$:
$$\tag{2}
a^2 - b^2 - c^2 = 0,
$$
and $\mathcal{G}(u)$ is a completely arbitrary function (not necessarily linear)!

This solution describes an arbitrary plane wave traveling on the kink solution, at the speed of light.